# How to find the innerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the value 12.5 as a variable by extracting it out of this piece of code.

```
<li style="background-color: transparent;">
<a href="#userModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal"></a>
<span style="background-color:#FDBF6F"></span>
12.5 GoCoins
</li>
```

I've tried doing some research but can't get my head around it, help appreciated.

```
var inthepot = 0
inthepot = +(document.querySelector("li")[0].innerHTML)
```

Comment: What is `inthepot`?

Comment: it's just a variable

Comment: Just use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `.querySelector`, you do not use the `[0]`. Instead, simply call the `.innerHTML`, and use string parsing to get your number:

```js
function getNumber(){
    alert(parseFloat(document.querySelector("li").innerHTML.split("</span>")[1].split(" ")[0]));
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<li style="background-color: transparent;">
<a href="#userModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal"></a>
<span style="background-color:#FDBF6F"></span>
12.5 GoCoins
</li>
  <button onclick="getNumber()">Click!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML`

> *The `Node.textContent` property represents the `text content` of a `node` and its `descendants`.*

[**`Unary plus (+)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), *The `unary plus operator` precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a `number`, if it isn't already.*

***Note:*** `Number` could be used as well instead of `Unary plus (+)`

```js
function getNumber() {
  alert(+document.querySelector("li").textContent.trim().split(" ")[0]);
}
```

```html
<li style="background-color: transparent;">
  <a href="#userModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal"></a>
  <span style="background-color:#FDBF6F"></span>
  12.5 GoCoins
</li>
<button onclick="getNumber()">Click!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution using regex:

https://jsfiddle.net/9vs9v7oL/1/

```
var my_li_contents = document.querySelector('li').innerHTML;
var coins = /^([0-9.]+) GoCoins$/m.exec(my_li_contents);
alert(coins[1]);
```